# how to add Spiderfier in Googlemaps api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerspiderfier

I am new to googlemaps. I have already read the [Overlapping Marker Spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) documentation but I am still confused about how to implement it into my maps.

Here is my attempt:

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, 48.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    });
    var locations = [[40.0000, 48.0000], [40.0000, 48.0000], [40.0000, 48.0000]];
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
            map: map
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You can find this code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanus/6jekA/1/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your code updated...

```
function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, 48.0000),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    });
    var locations =[ [40.0000, 48.0000],[40.0000, 48.0000],[40.0000, 48.0000]];

    oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,
        {markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true, keepSpiderfied: true, circleSpiralSwitchover: 40 });

    var marker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
           map: map
         });
         oms.addMarker(marker);
      }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: wow, thanks .. it's work now. many thanks,, now i can more advanced learning the google maps.

Comment: What is "MainMap" parameter? 

new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(MainMap,
        {markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true, keepSpiderfied: true, circleSpiralSwitchover: 40 });

Comment: I found the answer for that MainMap must have map object 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, 48.0000),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    });